# Packets out of order when connecting to MariaDB10 Synology

Tags: php, web, mariadb, nas, synology

I am trying to connect to my db on my synology in PHP.
I use the following code to do so :

```
try {   
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=192.168.1.45:3307;dbname=mydbname;charset=UTF8",$username, $pass);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The problem is that when I'm trying my code it tell me :
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away. Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=71

I looked on some site and made the following change on my "my.cnf" file in mariaDB10 :

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 256M
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 28800
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

My PHP version on my synology is set to 7.2.

I changed the pdo_mysql.default_socket to : /run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock

I don't find any clue on how to solve my problem. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What steps have you taken ....  Have you checked that mariadb is up and running on the machine .... have you enabled mariadb logging?  What do those log files say.  Is the port really 3307 and not 3306? did you change it?  are you able to access this mysql via command line client? ex mysql -h host_name -u user_name -p[password] ?  if so what was the outcome?  if you were unable to access via cmd line client & your using 192.something so i'm assuming its on another machine on some internal network? if so is there a firewall or something in the way?

Comment: my mariaDB10 is actually up and running, for the port it is 3307 by default (I've checked). When I execute mysql -h 192.168.1.45:3307 -u root -p [password] in SSH I've access to the command line. Where can I find the log file that you were speaking ? it is on another machine but on the same network actually, i havn't set any firewall actually.

Comment: Interesting log files will be created when you enable them in my.cnf I would look up the syntax that is for your version.  I would be looking for the general_log here is a reference https://mariadb.com/kb/en/general-query-log/#:~:text=The%20general%20query%20log%20is,can%20grow%20large%20quite%20quickly.  this will show you connections and disconnects and log of recieved queries

Comment: try enableing userstat in my.cnf userstat=1 userstat_running=1 then try to connect a few time and run select * from user_statistics where user='user_name' what do you see?  also when you modified the my.cnf did you restart mariadb service?

Comment: Also could you try setting your DSN like this mysql:host=192.168.1.45;port=3307;dbname=mydbname

Comment: Cengleby : For the log files, I checked nut nginx log (my http server) but nothing valuable came out.
After i tried to set userstat and userstat running in my "my.cnf" file, I cannot restart my mariadb service ?
I will try to set my dsn as you said thanks.
Edit : I have the same error after changing my DSN

Comment: So I tried and couldn't replicate the issue with remy php 7.2 and mariadb10.  So this doesn't look to be a bug.  This issue tends to be with connectivity ... So I got two more attempts #1 are you using the same user/password to connect to mariadb as you did with with cmd line? If not have you granted ability to accept remote connection from that user.... And #2 are you trying connect and use a prepared query or straight unprepared test query

Comment: Also on the MySQL machine can you netstat -ant | grep 3307 and put up the results

Comment: Also nmap 192.ipaddy | grep -i open. What does it say? Also try telnet 192.ipaddy 3307 does it hang?